# How do I automatically mint ERC-20 Tokens Every time the owner wallet transfers coins

Tags: solidity, erc-20, dapps

I want to start with a total_supply of 1,000 Tokens in the owner wallet.  Each token will represent a gram of gold. Every time 1 token is transferred from owner wallet to another wallet, the owner wallet should be refilled with 1 token.  Thus, always keeping the owner wallet at 1,000 Tokens.

**Questions:**

1. What is the best way to do this?

2. Is there a way where I wouldn't have to pay gas every time coins are minted to owner_wallet?

3. I'd like to accept Bitcoins and Alt coins for this token. What is a good process to have the owner tokens send automatically to people who have paid with Bitcoin and Alt coins?  Is there a Dapp or open source script you recommend looking at?

4. Do you have any recommendations or suggestions If I want each token to represent a commodity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function like this:

```
function mint(uint howMany, address to) public returns (bool) {
  totalSupply = safeAdd(totalSupply, howMany);
  balances[for] = safeAdd(balances[to], howMany);
  Transfer(0, to, howMany);
  return true;
}
```

Calling that instead of `transfer` will create new tokens. If you still want to use the transfer function (may be required if you use simpler ERC20 wallets) change the code to this:

```
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    if(msg.sender == owner) {

        mint(tokens, to);

    }else{
             balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
             balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
             Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
             return true;
     }
```

Sadly it is not possible to accept Bitcoin or Altcoins in an Ethereum smart contract or Dapp, you will have to rely on a third party solution.

Recommendations about tokens representing commodities: Don't do it. It is very hard to get a license to do stuff like that and you probably need a legal team and regular audits to do so.